# Why is SQL Server is adding a check constraint to my nocheck FK constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

SQL Server is adding a check constraint to my nocheck constraint.

I start with this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Subject_OrganizationSubjectRank] FOREIGN KEY([OrganizationId], [StatusId], [Rank])
REFERENCES [dbo].[OrganizationSubjectRanks] ([OrganizationId], [OrganizationSubjectStatusId], [Name])
GO
```

And SQL server adds this to my code every time I execute:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Subject_OrganizationSubjectRank]
GO
```

This is causing foreign key constraint errors.

How do I prevent SQL server from adding this check constraint to my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL server adds this to my code"?   When are the constraint errors occurring?

Comment: No it is not causing your errors. The manner in which you load data and execute these statements is causing the errors. That second statement simply causes the engine to check that your foreign key relationship is consistent with existing data.

Comment: @Tab Alleman, I create the code above and after I execute it I go back and see that SQL server has added the check constraint (the code below).

Comment: @SMor, I agree. We do not want the check, but it keeps being added by SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

When you create a constraint using WITH NOCHECK, all that means is that, at the time you ALTER the table and ADD the constraint, the constraint will not be checked to see if the data already in the table conflicts with it.

After that, it becomes a regular constraint like any other. All future INSERT/UPDATES will have to comply with the constraint. So if you refresh your SSMS and Script the table, you will just see the CONSTRAINT without any NOCHECK.

To summarize, NOCHECK only matters while you are altering the table.   After that, it has no effect, and the constraint acts the same as if you had not used NOCHECK when you created it.

If you are trying to permanently REMOVE the constraint, then you need to DROP it.

Comment: I wish to differ on a few points. 1- If you create a FK with `WITH NOCHECK` option and script the table you _WILL_ still see the `WITH NOCHECK`. 2- You _can_ disable a FK constraint for future INESRT/UPDATES with `NOCHECK` option in a _separate_ ALTER command _after_ the initial FK creation, although `WITH NOCHECK` option will indeed not affect future INSERT/UPDATES. `WITH NOCHECK` and `NOCHECK` have separate functionalities.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is to run:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Subject_OrganizationSubjectRank]
```

The explanation is that [`WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=WITH%20CHECK%20%7C%20WITH%20NOCHECK) and [`CHECK | NOCHECK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=see%20SET%20QUOTED_IDENTIFIER.-,%7B%20CHECK%20%7C%20NOCHECK%20%7D%20CONSTRAINT,-Specifies%20that%20constraint_name) have two separate functionalities. `WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK` applies to, and only to existing data at the time the command is run. `CHECK | NOCHECK` applies to, and only to new data.

When creating a FK Constraint, you have the `WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK` options regarding the existing data, but the `CHECK` option is automatically set. That is why you see the second command. In order to override the default of `CHECK` you need to explicitly run an additional `NOCHECK` command.

See this link for further reference: https://sqlpowered.com/foreign-keys-check-nocheck-and-with-check/